# Laravel Passport "auth:api" middleware acts as "web, auth" middleware

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have set up the **Laravel Passport** package for Laravel 5.3 just as described in the official documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#introduction).

I want the API to be consumed by a mobile application, so I am trying to implement **Password Grant Tokens**. I have created a password grant client, and the token request process...

```
$response = $http->post('http://my-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'username' => 'my@email.com',
        'password' => 'my-password',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);
```

...Just works as expected, returning an **access-token** and a **refresh-token** for one of my users.

On the one hand,

```
php artisan route:list
```

Lists correct middleware for api/user URI: **api,auth:api**

And driver for api guard is correctly set to **passport** in config/auth.php.
Summing up, every step of the installation process has been done (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#installation).

Defaults contents of api.php:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

The problem comes when I access to http://my-app.com/api/user, because it seems it is authenticating the request using the 'web' middleware, not the 'api'...
When I access, I am redirected to /login (login form) if the user was not logged in, and to /home if it was...

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you follow the directions [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) as far as utilizing your own API endpoints using a X-CSRF-TOKEN ?

Comment: @dargue3. Yes, I also included \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class, in Kernel.php, nothing changed. But really I do not want to consume my own API using JavaScript. It is about consuming it from an external mobile application, and for that I need the password grant type method... I still have the problem. Any other idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved! Just for the record, the solution:

I was sending the request to http://my-app.com/api/user with HTTP Header wrong. I was sending:

```
Type: Authorization - Content: Bearer: $accessToken
```

...and the correct way was:

```
Type: Authorization - Content: Bearer $accessToken (without colon)
```

I never thought it could be a typo... Anyway, the error was not easy to detect because the redirection to the login form misleaded me from the beginning. I believe it was such an strange behaviour indeed...

Comment: I knew is an old post, but worth to mention here by adding Authorization is still not working, you need to add one more Accept: "application/json" in your header too. This is for latest version Laravel 5.5

Comment: It may fix the problem, but not is the solution

Comment: okay, I really need to know how you solve this problem. I am having the same un authenticated error. here is the post... could you please check this out?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590953/middleware-protected-routes-unauthenticated-problem-laravel-passport

Comment: Commented on your post :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is removing `redirectTo()` from this file Authenticate middleware in `app/http/middleware/Authenticate.php`