# Laravel Passport middleware protected routes "Unauthenticated" problem

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel Passport for the authentication, so I put my routes into middleware protection.

### UPDATED

To make it clear, I am adding UsersController too.

```
public function getUser()
{
    $users = Auth::user();
    return response()->json($users);
}
```

//

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    /* users */
    Route::get('/users', 'Api\UsersController@getUser');

    /* fetch */
    Route::get('/articles', 'Api\ArticlesController@allArticles');
    Route::get('/article/{id}', 'Api\ArticlesController@singleArticle');
});
```

Of course, I need to log in, or I can't see the protected routes. I made an `AuthController` and inside that a controller login function.

**Controller**

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
    try {
        $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ]
        ]);
        return $response->getBody();
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
            return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
        }

        if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
            return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
        }

        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

In the frontend in my vuex, I have an action call.

```
retrieveToken(context, credentials){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.post("api/v1/login", {
                email: credentials.username,
                password: credentials.password,
            })
            .then(response => {
                const token = response.data.access_token;
                localStorage.setItem("access_token", token);
                context.commit("retrieveToken", token);
                resolve(resolve);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                reject(response);
            })
    })
},
```

Everything is fine. I store the token and use that for the login and delete it for the log out. But at the backend, something is missing. Because even if login, I still can't see the protected routes. Laravel's Auth doesn't know that user logged in.

Where should I put the token into the header? Inside the controller or login method? Or do I need to do something else?

Comment: please share the output of the `console.log(response)` from inside the retrieveToken function.

Answer (score 3):

> Also logged in user seeing pages only auth user can see.

How are you doing this? If the user can see what auth user can see, which means you are making `GET` request with auth token right? If you're using a passport, you should put the token into your Authorization header.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
```

Use this to put the token into your all axios request after you have login, then you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried to put it in `fetchToken()` 's inside then `.then()` part but still same error popping.

Comment: Try to check your header, is the `Authorization` header there?

Comment: when I logged in there, but when I refresh the page its gone.

Comment: It's because you only call the set axios Authorization header when you log in. The idea is there, try implementing this line of code into your application, so that when it refreshes it still logged in. E.g: saving it in cookies.

Comment: Then did you put the token into header when you load your application?

Comment: I think, i did not, because i am not sure how to do that :)

Comment: Is the view project inside your laravel project? If that, your should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749661/laravel-react-consume-api-with-laravel-authentication/55705327#55705327

Comment: @parabellum don’t you save the token in local storage?

Comment: I saved the token localStorage. And using that token (putting it on the header) when I fetching articles or users... for example like this. https://imgur.com/a/duEJIFT and I can see the preview of the json the console. But can't see the endpoint on BROWSER it's saying you must login... @NipunTharuksha redirecting me to login page

Comment: @Sanjaya please check this.

Comment: In order to hit the api and Passport, you need to append the `Content-type` `application/json` header to your requests. If you call endpoints from the browser, they will flow through the `web` middleware resulting in a login redirection.

Try calling the same endpoint from Postman instead of from the browser, appending the `Content-type` header to see the difference and let us know.

Comment: @parabellum What do you mean can see the preview of json and can't see the endpoint on the browser? Can you screenshot or describe it thoroughly?

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu here is the screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/CIqZONl you can see at image 1-2 ss that I checking the network section at the console. everything is fine. Users is there... 200 OK but when I try to check it at browser. it s giving me an error. ?????????? how is this possible?

Comment: When you access it through browser.. It is not using the header.. When you call the API using your application, you already specified the token in the header.. It is normal.

Answer (score 3):

In Login Component use

```
methods: {
    login() {
      var instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://apiendpoint.com/api/"
      });

      instance
        .post("/admin-login", {
          email: this.username,
          password: this.password,
          device_type: "Web",
          device_token: "Web"
        })
        .then(response => {
          // console.log(response);

          localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.data.token);
          this.$router.push("/");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
```

Then define the axios configuration in a file as Repository.js which can be used with all resources.

```
/******************** Repository js ****************/
import axios from "axios";
import router from "./router";

const baseDomain = "http://apiendpoint.com/api/";
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}/api`;

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL, // headers: {
    //  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('api_token')
    // },
    validateStatus: function(status) {
        if (status == 401) {
            router.push("/login");
        } else {
            return status;
        }
    }
});
api.interceptors.request.use(
    function(config) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        if (token == null) {
            console.log("Token Is empty");
            console.log("Redirecting to Login");
            router.push({ name: "login" });
        }

        if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        return config;
    },
    function(response) {
        return response;
        console.log(response);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error);

        return error;
    }
);
// Add a response interceptor
api.interceptors.response.use(
    function(response) {
        // Do something with response data
        return response;
    },
    function(error) {
        // Do something with response error
        console.log("Error Found");

        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
export default api;
```

And define all vue routes in Router.

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply [Consuming your api with javascript](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) I would suggest adding the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware to your web middleware group.

**From the docs:**

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

Otherwise, as others have stated, make sure to include the Authorization header and Content-Type header in your request.

Answer (score 0):

If you using authentication by token with laravel passport always be sure you set the authentication header (for any client call) `Authorization = Bearer your_token` for protected routes, when call it from client. I make a simple auth example with Laravel Passport and Vue.js and uploaded it to github please check it out [on this link](https://github.com/VarghaSabee/laravel-passport).I also recommend to you read [this post](https://medium.com/@martin.riedweg/laravel-5-7-api-authentification-with-laravel-passport-92b909e12528)

Your login in Laravel should looks like this

```
 public function login (Request $request) {

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if ($user) {

            if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
                $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
                $response = ['token' => $token];
                return response($response, 200);
            } else {
                $response = "Password missmatch";
                return response($response, 422);
            }

        } else {
            $response = 'User does not exist';
            return response($response, 422);
        }
```

my laravel routes, `'middleware' => ['json.response']`, I use to force json all the datas

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['json.response']], function () {

    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

    // public routes
    Route::post('/login', 'Api\AuthController@login')->name('login.api');
    Route::post('/register', 'Api\AuthController@register')->name('register.api');

    // private routes
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/logout', 'Api\AuthController@logout')->name('logout');
    });

});
```

my `guards` in `config/auth.php`

```
  'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

then in vue you can use vuex for store the token and the user data for reuse it `store/index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default new Vuex.Store({
    strict: debug,
    state: {
        auth: null,
        token: null,
        check:false
    },
    getters: {
        auth: state => state.auth,
        token: state => state.token,
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_TOKEN(state, token) {
            state.token = token
        },

        FETCH_auth_SUCCESS(state, auth) {
            state.auth = auth
            state.check = true
        },

        FETCH_auth_FAILURE(state) {
            state.token = null
        },

        LOGOUT(state) {
            state.auth = null
            state.token = null
            state.check = false
        },

        UPDATE_auth(state, { auth }) {
            state.auth = auth
        }
    },

    actions: {
        saveToken({ commit, dispatch }, { token, remember }) {
            commit('SET_TOKEN', token)

            // if you need store token in cookie (remember me option)
            // Cookies.set('token', token, { expires: remember ? 365 : null })
        },

        async fetchauth({ commit,state }) {
            try {
                axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${state.token}`;
                const { data } = await axios.get('/api/user')

                commit('FETCH_auth_SUCCESS', data)
            } catch (e) {
                //   Cookies.remove('token')
                commit('FETCH_auth_FAILURE')
            }
        },

        updateauth({ commit }, payload) {
            commit('UPDATE_auth', payload)
        },

        async logout({ commit,state }) {
            try {
                axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${state.token}`;
                await axios.get('/api/logout')
            } catch (e) {console.log(e) }

            // Cookies.remove('token')
            commit('LOGOUT')
        },
    }
});
```

***Note*** I set the token `axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ${state.token}';` on every axios call (protected routes), but you can do this globally once.

Login method in vue

```
 methods: {
    login() {
      console.log("Login");
      axios
        .post("/api/login", {
          email: this.form.email,
          password: this.form.password
        })
        .then(res => {
          // save token to vuex
          this.$store.dispatch("saveToken", { token: res.data.token });
          // get user data, store in vuex
          this.$store.dispatch("fetchauth");
          // redirect
          this.$router.push({path:'/dashboard'});
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  }
```

When you make call to the protected routes by `'auth:api'` first of all you need to set the token in the header to get access to resources. In axios is `axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ${state.token}';`.